# Sequencing CSS keyframe animations not working

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I'm testing the sequencing of a few CSS animations, with the delay property. It doesn't seem to be working. The delays don't match. I'm not sure what I may be doing wrong. Could someone help?

Here is my code pen: http://codepen.io/marineb/pen/RramrJ?editors=110. (this codepen has been updated with solution B).

I'm testing this in Chrome.

Thank you!

```
    .oo {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}

.logo {
  -webkit-animation-name: logo;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
}

.o--2 {
  background: pink;
  -webkit-animation-name: oo-2;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
}

.o--3 {
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-animation-name: oo-2;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
}

.o--4 {
  background: green;
  -webkit-animation-name: oo-2;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes logo {
  0% {
    margin-top: 5270px;
  }
  10% {
    margin-top: 5270px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes oo-2 {
  0% {
    margin-top: 5270px;
  }
  60% {
    margin-top: 5270px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve... you want each section fly in from the bottom.

You're getting a strange result because BEFORE the animation is run each section has no margin. Then you instantly give it a large margin (it jumps down the page) after the delay has run out, and then the animation causes the margin to shrink.

To achieve the desired effect you have two options.

A) Define your margin on the class so it starts with a huge margin.

B) use:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
```

This does two things. It makes the properties from the start of the animation (0% in your case) apply BEFORE the animation is started and while the delay is still counting down. And then it also makes the properties from the end of the animation (100%) stick AFTER the animation has finished. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode for more information.

Also if you intend for the sections to fade in at about the 60% mark you'll need to either add opacity:0 to the 0% keyframe, or you'll need to add it to the CSS class. For the same reasons stated above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, that all makes sense. I've opted for option B, and updated the codepen accordingly.